# C - how would compiler optimization affect a for loop with no body?

Tags: c, for-loop, optimization, compiler-optimization

I have some legacy code where a timewasting loop has been included to allow time for an eeprom read to complete (bad practice):

```
for(i = 0; i < 50; i++);
```

However, peculiar things happen when compiler optimizations are switched on for speed. It is not necessarily connected with that statement, but I would like to know if the compiler might just optimize the time delay away

Comment: If the loop has no observable effect? It can for sure. If you just must have that loop, have it do something that cannot easily be optimized away, like reading a volatile variable.

Comment: Yes, it might do so indeed. Why don't you check the disassembly and see for yourself?

Comment: So running that program on an a faster machine will result in errors?

Comment: @knivil No chance of running the prog on a faster machine unfortunately, but in principle you are correct. It's not very good practice, and there's lots more stuff like that. I am having to go through largely undocumented code (documenting as I work out what's happening) looking for bugs

Comment: Here is another line using a while loop to wait for data to become available

while(!(AT91C_BASE_SPI1->SPI_SR & AT91C_SPI_RDRF));

Comment: On what kind of hardware is this code running ? And what compiler are you using ?

Comment: if the data is volatile or global, `while` isn't optimized out

Comment: In embedded world it's quite normal to disable optimizations for functions which use this kind of timing. It's not portable code from one compiler to another, but if you don't need to change one, it's usually easiest just to disable optimizations for such functions in legacy code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It's an IAR compiler and an embedded MCU - AT91SAM7X256 running at 55MHz

Comment: @user694733 Unfortunately I'm running out of speed and need to optimize

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It doesn't matter if the variable is at file scope. The compiler can then simply replace the loop with `i=50;`. Only `volatile` matters to ensure that the loop is executed.

Comment: You can check the assembly code generated by your compiler and see what happens when you add an optimization flag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on the type of `i`. If it is just a plain integer type that isn't used apart from inside the loop, there are no side effects and the compiler is free to optimize away the whole thing.

If you declare `i` as `volatile` however, the compiler is forced to generate code that increments the variable and reads it, at each lap of the loop.

This is one of many reasons why you should not use "burn-away" loops like these in embedded systems. You also occupy 100% CPU and consume 100% current. And you create a tight coupling between your system clock and the loop, which isn't necessarily linear.

The professional solution is always to use an on-chip hardware timer instead of "burn-away" loops.

Answer (score 8):

Lundin answer explains why it happens properly, so no need to paraphrase.

That said, if you really need to keep the old behaviour in your loop but optimize the rest, the easiest way would be to put this active delay loop in one function in one file:

```
#include <active_delay.h>   // the corresponding header file
void active_delay(int d)
{
   // do not build with optimize flags on!
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < d; i++);
}
```

and build this file *without any optimizing flags on*.

Build the rest of your code with optimizing flags on to benefit from optimizer on "normal" code.

Note that because of function call overhead and the very short execution time of the loop, the delay slightly increases when moving from inline call to a function in a separate object file.

You may want to reduce `d` value to match previous timing (if it's necessary)

Comment: Moving other file might not even be necessary (some IAR versions have  `#pragma optimize=none` for functions). But anyway, point of this answer is correct: use optimization where it matters, and disable where you must.

Comment: Though note that some embedded compilers are known to perform various optimizations even when to optimization flags are set. When in doubt, disassemble.

Comment: @user694733 thanks. The point of the answer was: if optimization was off at first and it worked, then leave it off where it matters!

Comment: @Lundin correct, but in that case, the code worked with the same compiler without optimizations, so at worst you're not changing anything (and you could even reduce the counter because of the overhead made by the call)