# Rewrite the following C function as an assembly-language subroutine with the same behavior

Tags: assembly, mips, delay

```
void delay( int ms ) /* Wait a number of milliseconds, 
                     specified by the parameter value. */
{
    int i;
    while( ms > 0 )
   {
        ms = ms – 1;
          /* Executing the following for loop should take 1 ms */
   for( i = 0; i < 4711; i = i + 1 ) 
          /* The constant 4711 must be easy to change! */
   {
          /* Do nothing. */
   }
  }
}
```

I have converted this as following and this subroutine is part a bigger subroutine.

```
delay:
PUSH    ($s0)
PUSH    ($ra)

addi    $s0,$0,0            #i = 0
addi    $t1,$0,4711
move    $t0,$a0         #move the argument to t0
while:
bgt     $t0,$s0,done        #branch to done if ms > 0
addi    $t0,$t0,-1      #decrement ms by 1  
for:
beq     $s0,$t1,done
addi    $s0,$s0,1
j       for
j       while
done:   

POP ($ra)
POP ($s0)
jr  $ra
nop
```

Test your program using MARS. Adjust the constant in the for loop to get a delay of 1000 ms
when delay is called with a parameter value of 1000, and a delay of 3000 ms when delay is called
with a parameter value of 3000.

Q1:So I'm not sure if I converted it correctly.

Q2:How to adjust that constant to get that amount of delay.

Any suggestion, hints would be great.Thanks in advance.

Comment: note that there's no guarantee that the C counterpart does the loop at all. Optimizer may remove that. check that post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415271/c-how-would-compiler-optimization-affect-a-for-loop-with-no-body

Comment: Q2: https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html Look up system call 32.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, are you claiming producing no assembly at all is a valid 'solution' to this homework question?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: Surely he's claiming that a conforming C compiler could elide the loop.   Not that a student should do so.  Want to make sure your C compiler doesn't elide the loop?  One option: `volatile int i;`.

Comment: @Michael: This clearly is a homework assignment, and `sleep` doesn't allow you to specify the unit duration (ie it's ms only), the inner `for` loop would, theoretically, allow you to write a 25 microsecond-based interval

Comment: `nanosleep()` is the best way when it's available... otherwise, compiile in C without optimization on, then disassemble to make sure! not to mention: the C loop may be less optimized than the same asm loop.

Comment: This C code can be completely removed on optimisation; there is no observable behaviour. Remove all other code than the return (I assume `jr  $ra`) and make clear that you highly optimised it as every good compiler since the 1990ies would.

Comment: I have removed the *C* tag as I think this question is unrelated to it and it tends to attract off-topic comments. If you believe it was determinant, please feel free to rollback or ping me in a comment (with @margaret) to ask to get it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not considering all the fuss about the empty observable behaviour as I consider this an assembly exercise with a misworded command text.

So henceforward I pretend the code is not C but a new language called *C pseudo-code* with a syntax similar to that of C and a semantic where every statement has observable side effects.

---

The assembly code is incorrect.
I'm not going to correct your mistakes or write any code, I'll just point *some* of them out.

---

The implementation of the `for`

```
# $s0 = i
# $t1 = 4711

for:
  beq     $s0,$t1,done
  addi    $s0,$s0,1
j       for
```

Has at least two issues:

1. It jumps to `done` upon exit.
   This corresponds to exiting the `while` loop too, instead the `for` in C pseudo-code do another iteration of the `while` on exit.
2. The register `$s0` is never re-initialized.
   The counter `i` is initialized on every iteration of the `while` - your implementation, instead, do it once at the beginning.

The implementation of the `while` condition is

```
# $s0 = i
# $t0 = ms

bgt $t0, $s0, done        #branch to done if ms > 0
```

You can see for your self, with the help of the comments, that it corresponds to `ms > i` as your code is standing.
You have, in MIPS, a register that is always zero.

---

Some tips:

- **You can avoid using any `$s` register.**
  There are enough `$t` registers available - saving a `$s` immediately makes the reader think of an inner call, while there is none in the code.
- **Write the C pseudo-code in simpler form.**
  You can rewrite the `for` as

  ```
  i = 0;
  for_begin:
     if (i >= 4711)
        goto for_end

        /* FOR BODY */

        i = i + 1;
  goto for_begin

  for_end:
  ```

  This should be easier to translate into assembly.

Comment: Thanks now it's working , I should drink more water lol. not `btg`   should be `ble` i see now. i also fixed other issues that you mentioned thanks once again.